# How do I select from MySQL all rows that fall within a month but may have dates in the next month?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks kind of like this;

```
ID | netID | indate             | outdate           | name    | org
=====================================================================
1  |  50   | 2020-03-31 23:50   | 2020-03-31 23:32  | Bill    | orgA
2  |  50   | 2020-03-31 23:51   | 2020-03-31 23:32  | Fred    | orgA
3  |  50   | 2020-04-01 00:02   | 2020-04-01 00:05  | Sam     | orgA

4  |  51   | 2020-03-31 23:50   | 2020-03-31 23:32  | Harry   | orgB    
5  |  51   | 2020-03-31 23:51   | 2020-03-31 23:32  | George  | orgB
6  |  51   | 2020-04-01 00:02   | 2020-04-01 00:05  | Tom     | orgB
```

I need to write a report by org & year & month, but any row that has the same netID must be included even if it its in a different year or month.  And I can't say "WHERE netID = 50" for example because I don't know what netID's are in the month '03' of the year '2020'.

I'm looking for the first three rows to be returned if I need a March 2020 report for orgA.

Below doesn't work for what I need, and I can't figure out how to get all of the rows for each netID regardless of month. Can someone please give me an example of how to retrieve them?

```
SELECT date(iodate) as logdate,
       Name,
       netID,
       COALESCE( netID, 'Month Total') AS netTTL,
       COUNT(ID) AS idCount,
       month(logdate AS month    
  FROM table
 WHERE org = 'orgA'
   AND year(indate) = '2020'
   AND month(iodate) = '03'
 GROUP BY year(logdate), month, netID WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Even afteri removed all the errors, i can't still run it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3700088247237ad8b4e0ae33f11ee12   What should the resukt look like

Comment: There are two things that I want to know, where is `iodate` in your table example? And does the `logdate` column in `month(logdate) AS month` in `SELECT` is from `date(iodate) as logdate`? Because `logdate` is also not in your table example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to get all rows where any row exists, that has the same net ID, the requested organization and a date in the requested range is getting the net IDs for the range and organization in a derived table and then join the table.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t2.netid
                    FROM elbat t2
                    WHERE t2.org = 'orgA'
                          AND t2.indate >= '2020-03-01'
                          AND t2.indate < '2020-04-01') x
            INNER JOIN elbat t1
                       ON t1.netid = x.netid;
```

A few notes:

- You should use range expressions rather than applying `year()` and `month()` to the date in the `WHERE` clause. Range expressions can use indexes and speed up the query.
- In your query you have columns/expressions that are neither applied to an aggregation function nor in the `GROUP BY`. Though older or badly configured MySQL servers accept that, it may produce funny results. But since you didn't further explain what you want to do there, there's not much more to say here than "You're doing it wrong!".

Comment: #sticky_bit Please explain what you mean by "columns/expressions that are neither applied to an aggregation function nor in the GROUP BY" so I can better understand. In the mean time your SQL worked, I'm still playing with it a bit for my need but I like it.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser: `name` for example isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause and no aggregation function (`min()`, `max()`, `sum()`, `avg()`, `count()`, ...) is applied to it.